# How to close an Alert dialog without a button in FLUTTER

Tags: flutter

I want to show a circle indicator when the user presses the login button. But sometimes an error can occur such as a Wrong email or wrong password. In that case, the circle indicator should be stopped and the error message should be shown. There is no button in circle indicator alert dialog. I want it to automatically close when an error found

```
onPressed: () async {
                      AuthResult user;
                      progressIndi();

                      try {
                        user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pass);
                      } catch (err) {
                        finderror(err.code);
                      }
```

**finderror** function will find the error message to show. 
**progressIndi()** function will show the alert dialog. I tried to implement it with stacks. But it's only showing changes when I close the dialog box and press the login button again.

```
void progressIndi() {
showDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return IndexedStack(
      index: isError,
      children: <Widget>[

        AlertDialog(
          content: new Row(
            children: [
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
                  child: Text(" Loading")),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Error Found"),
          content: Text(errorMessage),
          actions: <Widget>[
            // usually buttons at the bottom of the dialog
            new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("Try Again"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                isError = 0;
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

}

I know that alert dialog can be closed using the button and Navigator.of(context).pop() .
Please, anyone, give me a hint to close the alert dialog from outside without a button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the dialog when an error occurs by calling Navigator.of(context).pop() just after the exception occurs and then show another dialog for error. Hope this helps.

```
  AuthResult user;
                      progressIndi();

                      try {
                        user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: pass);
                      } catch (err) {
//Use pop here.
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
//make findError open another dialog.
                        finderror(err.code);
                      }
```

Comment: Yup, it won't. Since you are using barrierDismissable: false, You are safe to call Navigator.of(context).pop() without popping the current page but pop the dialog. Hope this helps. :)